# Add a page before first page in TCPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I have a HTML document which I'm converting to PDF using TCPDF. The HTML document contains several html tables. This works fine. But, I also need to add the number of pages in the PDF doc to the first page. Is there any solution to build the PDF file and then add a page before current first page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea I found is to clone the TCPDF instance and get the returned number of pages:

```
$tmp_pdf = clone $pdf;
$tmp_pdf->AddPage();
$tmp_pdf->writeHTML($report, true, false, true, false, '');
$num_pages = $tmp_pdf->getNumPages();
unset($tmp_pdf);
$report = preg_replace('#\{num_pages\}#is', $num_pages, $report);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works with HTML, but I found a solution that worked for me with movePage. 
You create the page, get its position and move it to the first position :

```
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'My content');
// Get the current page number
$pageNo = $pdf->PageNo(); 
// First page of the document
$toPage = 1;
$pdf->movePage($pageNo, $toPage);
```

Official example here : https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_044/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to calculate how many pages there will be based on the size of your tables.  I would read in all the html data, measure it, and then start to make the PDF.

Comment: thx for your reply but it wouldn't work because I've some pagebreak tags inside...